# undefined number of Or-operation on List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a List with n-entries. `List<MyClass> result`

And I have another List with n-Filter options `List<string> filters`

What i want is to return the result List filtered by the other List.

For an AND-operation its easy like this:

```
foreach (var filter in filters) 
{
     results = results.Where(x => x.Result == filter);
}
```

But how to code for an OR-Operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Where`in combination with `Any` in this case:

```
results = results.Where(x => filters.Any(f => f == x.Result));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx

Others ways:

```
//Contains, see DAXaholic's post
results = results.Where(x => filters.Contains(x.Result));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx

```
//List Extension method 'Exists'
results = results.Where(x => filters.Exists(f => f == x.Result));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you

```
results.Where(x => filters.Contains(x.Result))
```